# django group subcategory with category slug

Tags: python, django, grouping

Trying to make a linkdirectory page with categories and subcategories, have the following so far, problem is that i can't get the category as a link

```
models.py
class Category(models.Model):
"""Category"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

                #self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
def __unicode__(self):
return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
"""Sub Category"""
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(SubCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
return self.name
```

and

```
views.py
@require_GET
def links(request):
"""Linkdirectory Page"""
categories = Category.objects.all()
subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
return render(request, 'links.html', {'categories':         categories,             'subcategories': subcategories,})
```

in order to group the subcategories by category i used the following in

```
{% regroup subcategories|dictsort:"category_id" by category as     categories_list %}

<ul>
{% for categories in categories_list %}
<li>{{ categories.grouper }}
           <li> <a href="/links/{{ categories.slug }}">{{ categories.name     }}</a></li>
<ul>
    {% for item in categories.list %}
            <li><a href="/links/{{ item.slug }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This all works nicely grouping the subcats together

CAT1
--subcatLINK1
--subcatLINK2

but what i would like to have is

CATLINK1
--subcatLINK1
--subcatLINK2

Not sure how and if its possible to replace the grouper string with a custom link as like the subcategory link or if i'm going the right way around this

Edited, adding Bakkals approach below:
EDIT AGAIN ;) nevermind, i had to update the naming scheme aswell obviously, below code is the working version.
trying to use category.subcategory_set.all as suggested by Bakkal

```
{% for category in categories %}
<ul>
<li><a href="/links/{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% for subcategory in category.subcategory_set.all %}
<ul>
            <li><a href="/links/{{ subcategory.slug }}">{{     subcategory.name }}</a></li>
</ul>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SubCategory` contains a ForeignKey to `Category`, You can use `category.subcategory_set` to get the subcategories.

I find this simpler than manually doing the grouping you did by the `category_id`

So you can e.g. pass `categories` as a queryset of all `Category` objects as the context to your template, and then within the template

```
{% for category in categories %}
    ...
    {% for subcategory in category.subcategory_set.all %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not completely, but it looks like the right track. when using this i get  empty bulleted lists, however the structure is OK, the links are not showing for each bullet

Comment: use `prefetch_related` to reduce the number of queries being made. e.g. `categories = Category.objects.all().prefetch_related('subcategory_set')`

Comment: this works, had to update the naming within the links themselves as well obviously, many thanks again